# Jmeter - can't pass property to JDBC connector

Tags: properties, jmeter

I have a **setUp** thread Group and a **normal** thread Group. Jmeter runs the thread groups consecutively.

Into the setup group I select a username from a database and I put that into a property with a JSR223 sampler like this:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
JMeterUtils.setProperty("schemaProp", vars.get("schemaVar_1"));
```

Into the second thread I have a JDBC Connector which access the property like this:

```
${__property(sshUserProp,)}
```

But It doesn't work.

**LOG**:

```
2021-12-16 08:54:58,802 DEBUG o.a.j.p.j.c.DataSourceElement: Driver: org.postgresql.Driver DbUrl: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:50539/JB7 User: sshUserProp
```

The JDBC Connector doesn't really see the property, although it is actually set, cause I can access it with another JSR223 sampler:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
log.info ("------------------------- MESSAGE: " + JMeterUtils.getProperty("sshUserProp"))
```

**LOG**:

```
2021-12-16 08:54:58,961 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: ------------------------- MESSAGE: 160116
```

Comment: You must set JDBC configuration values before loading the jmx, for example using property file or parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, at least not with JMeter 5.4.1, looking into [JDBC Connection Configuration source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/config/DataSourceElement.java#L112) the element is being set up in the `testStarted()` function and according to the [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestStateListener.html#testStarted--)

> Called **just before the start of the test from the main engine thread**. This is before the test elements are cloned. Note that not all the test variables will have been set up at this point.

So you need to determine the user name **beforehand** somewhere somehow, i.e. by running another JMeter test and saving the username(s) into a file via [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) and then readine the username from the file using [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function or pass the username via -J command-line argument - this way your current approach with [__property() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) will work.